# Which java sdk and android sdk version should I install on win 10 64 bits pc?

Tags: java, android

Planning to develop android apps using android studio 3.5. Which java sdk and android sdk version should I install on win 10 64 bits pc?

Comment: What happens when you setup the recomended download for your platform? https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads Are there errors?

Comment: I have not installed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest stable version for both.

Comment: Latest Stable Java is Java 13... Android doesn't work with that

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio comes with an embedded JDK. If you don't want to bother with installing Java, then you shouldn't have to.

The Android SDK version you choose depends on which devices you plan on running your application on